# Go Test always passses why?

Tags: testing, go

I installed go and tried the first part on [How to write go code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html)

And after a while of not seeing the desired result I notice go test always passes, always!

What am I missing?

```
$ go version
go version go1
$ mkdir -p src/example/math 

$ cat >src/example/math/sum_test.go <<.
> package math
>
> import "testing"
>
> func SumTest( t *testing.T ) {
>    t.Errorf("ssss %d", 1 )
> }
> .

$ go test example/math
ok      example/math    0.044s
```

I'm using windows x64 and I'm using git-bash as shell

Comment: Despite me not knowing Go, I don't see any condition that would cause 1 to fail.

Comment: I typed more that I should. This is the test function: http://golang.org/doc/code.html#Testing  and it keep passing so I removed everything until I end up with e.Errof which is similar to `raise Exception` in Python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [go command man page](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#Description_of_testing_functions):

A test function is one named `TestXXX` (where `XXX` is any alphanumeric string not starting with a lower case letter) and should have the signature,

```
func TestXXX(t *testing.T) { ... }
```

Your `SumTest()` function doesn't follow that pattern, and is likely to be ignored.
This should work better:

```
func TestSum( t *testing.T )
```

Comment: Doh, missed that part! Thank you VonC